# extract email from variable in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to extract email address from {{e}}(which contains string with email) in below snippet

```
{% for e in error %}
          {{e}}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What isn't working? what relationship is the email to `e`?

Comment: {{e}} contains a string like "Email test@gmail.com is already assigned to this campaign". I want email address from string(here test@gmail.com).

Comment: Ok great, so what have you tried? there are numerous different ways of doing this

Comment: I tried in javascript it worked but I want to do this in django template(by using filters.)

Comment: You should update your question to show what you have tried - your comment negates user3270602's answer, and what you have researched and why that hasnt help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own template filter `get_email` which will give the value of the email from the string passed to it.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_email(value):
    email = value.strip().split()[1] # get the 2nd word from the sentence
    return email
```

Then in your template, you can access `email` by something like:

```
{{e|get_email}}
```

Value of `e` obtained after applying the `get_email` template filter on the string `'Email test@gmail.com is already assigned to this campaign'` will be `test@gmail.com` assuming `email` is always at the 2nd place in the sentence.

Comment: Thanks, but email is not exactly at the 2nd position so I modified the function to get email from any where in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract email using javascript:

```
var error = 'sdabhikagathara@rediffmail.com, "assdsdf" <dsfassdfhsdfarkal@gmail.com>, "rodnsdfald ferdfnson" <rfernsdfson@gmal.com>, "Affdmdol Gondfgale" <gyfanamosl@gmail.com>, "truform techno" <pidfpinfg@truformdftechnoproducts.com>, "NiTsdfeSh ThIdfsKaRe" <nthfsskare@ysahoo.in>, "akasdfsh kasdfstla" <akashkatsdfsa@yahsdfsfoo.in>, "Bisdsdfamal Prakaasdsh" <bimsdaalprakash@live.com>,; "milisdfsfnd ansdfasdfnsftwar" <dfdmilifsd.ensfdfcogndfdfatia@gmail.com>';    

function extractEmails (text)
{
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}

$("#emails").text(extractEmails(text).join('\n'));
```